# What am I doing wrong with Chrome's FileSystem API?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

Trying to use Chrome's API here (nothing fancy, just want to get the permission box up at least) and no matter what example I find I seem to run into problems.

For example this [github link here](https://gist.github.com/greenido/979770).. Now pretty much all of these examples are so old that the language is different now. `RequestFileSystem` is Chrome specific now with `webkitRequestFileSystem` and `FileError` has been replaced by `DOMError`. Here's the relevant javascript, with those parts swapped out to their modern equivalents:

```
            window.webkitRequestFileSystem  = window.webkitRequestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        // Handle errors
        function errorHandler(e) {
            var msg = '';
            switch (e.code) {
                case DOMError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                    msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                    break;
                case DOMError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                    msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                    break;
                case DOMError.SECURITY_ERR:
                    msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                    break;
                case DOMError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                    msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                    break;
                case DOMError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                    msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                    break;
                default:
                    msg = 'Unknown Error';
                    break;
            };
            console.log('Error: ' + msg);
        }

        // Init and write some data to a file
        function onInitFs(fs) {
            fs.root.getFile('log-f-api.txt', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.isFile === true;
                fileEntry.name == 'log-f-api.txt';
                fileEntry.fullPath == '/log-f-api.txt';
                // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
                fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                    fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                        console.log('Write completed.');
                    };
                    fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
                        console.log('Write failed: ' + e);
                    };
                    // Create a new Blob and write it to log.txt.
                    if (!window.BlobBuilder && window.WebKitBlobBuilder)
                        window.BlobBuilder = window.WebKitBlobBuilder; // in Chrome 12.
                    var bb = new BlobBuilder(); 
                    bb.append("some stuff");
                    console.log("bb size:"+bb.size);
                    bb.append('put some nice text in our file....');
                    var ourData = bb.getBlob('text/plain');
                    fileWriter.write(ourData); 
                }, errorHandler);
            }, errorHandler);
        }
        // start the party
        $(function() {
            document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML = 'start the tests';
            window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 5*1024*1024, onInitFs,errorHandler);
        });
```

I've tried out a few different examples and no matter what I just "Error: Unknown Error" in console... I know that Chrome won't allow this API over `file://`, using both Apache over localhost as well as hosting it on a test server produces the same result. Everything I can find says it should work in Chrome 66, the version I'm trying to get this to work on. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what line exactly is the error occuring?

Comment: console says `console.log('Error: ' + msg);` :-/ I also don't know what the difference is exactly, but in Chrome it is a grey error message & not a red

Comment: right well that's because `e.code` is not any of the provided switch values, so `default:` is being executed. Find out what the value of `e.code` is and then look up what it means

Comment: Did you actually try to debug in devtools which is the first thing to do in such cases? Set up some breakpoints, step through the code, inspect the results, variables, parameters, etc.